# Unicode toUppercase vs OrdinalIgnoreCase / InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Tags: c#, unicode

According to the Unicode the character U+0131 
[LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I](https://codepoints.net/U+0131) has as uppercase the ASCII character 'I'
and the character U+017F '' [LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S](https://codepoints.net/U+017F) has as uppercase the ASCII character 'S'

The following code fails in both checks

```
string check = "\u0131\u017F";
if ( string.Equals( check, "IS",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Ok!" );
}
if ( string.Equals( check, "IS", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Ok!" );
}
```

Given that the Unicode toUppercase mappings as defined in [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html) are not linguistic, but invariant, what are exactly the rules that OrdinalIgnoreCase and InvariantCultureIgnoreCase follow ?

Comment: Note that it's simpler to reproduce by just using `Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(...))`. It would be helpful if you'd edit the code into a [mcve] rather than a snippet - just so users can copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: Interestingly, calling `ToUpper` *does* return "IS".

Comment: There are already a *lot* of existing posts about this issue, google ".net turkish i problem" to find them so we don't have to do this all over again.  Second hit is by one of the SO founders who ran into it while creating SO :)

Comment: @JonSkeet it returns IS becuase it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` by default. But if you do `ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (to reflect what is used in question) - it will not return "IS".

Comment: JonSkeet: But ToUpperInvariant is not

@HansPassant:  I do known those issues. The problem is that those conflicts appear as exceptions to the way OrdinalIgnoreCase behaves. My question is what are the rules that OrdinalIgnoreCase follows? Clearly is not following the standard Unicode toUppercase mappings.

Comment: @HansPassant this doesn't look like "turkish i" problem. Question is - how to make case insensetive and culture insensetive string comparision (or alternatively - how to convert string to upper\lower case according to unicode general, culture-independent rules). Invariant culture rules (which are used by both  OrdinalIgnoreCase and InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) don't follow that "global" unicode casing table, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any stable logic to interpret how OrdinalIgnoreCase behaves and I decided to use brute force and write custom Mapper class that can handle comparing and getting the hash code of char* segments.

The reason of this is to support OrdinalIgnoreCase comparisons and equality checks for the recently introduced ReadOnlySpan and perhaps later to implement a string Dictionary that can accept lookups from strings and ReadOnlySpan

A very early version of the Mapper is committed here [OrdinalIgnoreCase.Map.cs](https://github.com/panost/ecl.Unicode/blob/master/src/GenIOCMap/Testing/OrdinalIgnoreCase.Map.cs)

And while the Compare and Equal test pass, the GetHashCode fails because of some inconsistent behavior on the Unicode block [Deseret](https://codepoints.net/deseret). It appears that OrdinalIgnoreCase's GetHashCode algorithm converts Deseret's lower case letters to upper, while Equals and Compare are not. You can observe that behavior in the code at [Deseret.cs](https://github.com/panost/ecl.Unicode/blob/master/src/GenIOCMap/Testing/Deseret.cs)